# Mathematica more input is needed

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm not much familiar with this programming language and I just need to run one function to compute some coeficients.

```
f[x] = x^2 - 2 x + 2
g[x] = x^3 - 2 x^2 - 2 x - 2
f1 = Root[f[x], 1];
f2 = Root[f[x], 2];
g1 = Root[g[x], 1];
g2 = Root[g[x], 2];
g3 = Root[g[x], 3];

foo[rootList, alpha, beta] :=
(
    res = {};
    For[i = 1, i <= Length[rootList], i++, alphaI = rootList[[i]];
        For[j = 1, j <= Length[rootList], j++, betaJ = rootList[[j]];
            If[betaJ != beta,
            (
                kor = Simplify [(alphaI - alpha) / (beta - betaJ)];
                res = Append[res, N[kor, 5]];
            ),
            ]
        ]
    ]
    Return[res];
)
roots = [f1, f2, g1, g2, g3];
cs = foo[roots, f1, g1]
```

this piece of code gives me this error:

```
Syntax::tsntxi: "For[i=1,i<=Length[rootList],i++,alphaI=rootList[[i]];" is incomplete; more input is needed.
```

And don't see what is wrong. I'm using mathematica 10.4

Answer (score 0):

Fixing the syntax errors.

```
f[x_] := x^2 - 2 x + 2 
g[x_] := x^3 - 2 x^2 - 2 x - 2 
f1 = Root[f[x], 1];
f2 = Root[f[x], 2];
g1 = Root[g[x], 1];
g2 = Root[g[x], 2];
g3 = Root[g[x], 3];

foo[rootList_, alpha_, beta_] :=
 (
  res = {};
  For[i = 1, i <= Length[rootList], i++, alphaI = rootList[[i]];
   For[j = 1, j <= Length[rootList], j++, betaJ = rootList[[j]];
    If[betaJ != beta,
     (
      kor = Simplify[(alphaI - alpha)/(beta - betaJ)]; 
      res = Append[res, N[kor, 5]];
      )
     ]
    ]
   ];
  res
  )
roots = {f1, f2, g1, g2, g3};
cs = foo[roots, f1, g1]
```